# can casting away constness lead to undefined behavior?

Tags: c, casting, constants

```
const int a = 10
int *p = (int*) &a;
*p = 20;
printf("a = %d", a);
```

Is it possible to output either 10 or 20, depending on the compiler?

Comment: I gave your question a title that summarizes its contents. Don't use such generic titles as you did, they don't help anybody.

Comment: [C/C++ changing the value of a const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583076/c-c-changing-the-value-of-a-const)

Comment: [Can we modify the value of a const variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245333/can-we-modify-the-value-of-a-const-variable)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As it's written, your code has undefined behavior, so yes, you could get 10 or 20 or anything else (e.g., an access violation).

Answer (score 15):

> Is it possible to output either 10 or 20, depending on the compiler?

Yes, or even nasal demons can appear. The behavior of this program is **undefined,** the code is ill-formed, because modifying a `const` object is a constraint violation.

Comment: + for `constraint violation` its called const-constraint - I like correct terminologies.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Unrelated: thanks for the dupe links.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have read these answers many times. I had same confusion in past. actually question is good and obvious one.

Answer (score 6):

It's undefined behavior:

C11 6.7.3 Type qualifiers

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use
>   of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined. If an attempt is
>   made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is undefined behaviour, and I think this is where is tells about it.

C99 Section 6.7.3 Paragraph 5

> **If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, the behavior is undefined**. If an attempt is made to refer to an
>   object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue
>   with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.115)

Answer (score 3):

When you do `*p=20`, you are trying to change the value of a constant, which is not allowed.