# XCode C compiler gives different result about integer pointer to const integer value, why?

Tags: c, xcode, pointers

In XCode I've tried to manipulate `const int` value by using pointer. Here is the code:

```
const int con = 5;

int *p;
p = &con;

(*p) +=1;

printf("Add of constant:%p\n",&con);
printf("Add of pointer:%p\n",p);

printf("%d - %d",con,*p);
```

Result is like that on XCode:

```
Add of constant:0x7fff5fbff79c
Add of pointer:0x7fff5fbff79c
5 - 6
```

but on linux virtual machine values of `con` and `*p` is same `6`.

Why there is a difference between values on XCode?

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile with clang (what Xcode uses). The error "Assigning to 'int *' from 'const int *' discards qualifiers" should be produced. If it isn't, you're settings are incredibly forgiving. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12245370/1322972).

Comment: Did you check the generated code? I could imagine that the compiler doesn't read `con` as it is const and not volatile and immediately puts the value 5 into parameter list for `printf`. You might try to use `volatile const int con = 5;` Or you might stop abusing weird pointers. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh yes volatile did work, I got 6 for both value. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this with VisualStudio, get the same result as with XCode. Assembly listing proved @Gerhardh point:

- `(*p) +=1;` successfully increases value of `con` in RAM
- `printf("Add of constant:%p\n",&con);` prints address of this memory correctly
- `printf("%d - %d",con,*p);` doesn't read `con` value from RAM, but passes 5 directly into printf. Optimization threw away unnecessary read for value known at compile time. Here is related assembly listing

---

```
printf("%d - %d",con,*p);

mov         eax,dword ptr [p]                   //get p
mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax]                 //get *p
push        ecx                                 //push *p (3rd param)
push        5                                   //push 5 (2nd param). No read of con
push        offset string "%d - %d" (415800h)   //push addr of format string (1st param)
call        dword ptr [__imp__printf (4182BCh)] //call printf()
```

Obviously, compiler on your VM didn't perform the same optimization.

Comment: You mean const variable act like a macro?

Comment: No. The compiler knows that you initialzed it with 5. And you are not allowed to modify it. Without volatile keyword the compiler is not forced to read it again for each access.

Comment: In described case yes. Compiler replaced `printf("%d - %d",con,*p);` with `printf("%d - %d",5,*p);` since con value is expected to be known at compile time.

Comment: If you have a register of some clock hardware it would be an option to defibe the variable const volatile. The you mustn't write to it but it can change autonatically. Due to volatile it must be read each time. This is not how a macro works

Comment: @Gerhardh, Generally speaking, you are totally right. `const` and macro are different approaches and they never meant to be the same thing. But @pcbtt is trying to understand code generated for this particular case with `printf` and indeed it's identical to the following: `#define con 5 <new line> printf("%d - %d",con,*p);`. So precise answer should be "const and macro aren't the same thing, but in this particular case they behave identically"

Comment: If the mechanism is totally different then I would not emphazise that the result is similar in this case. If you don't point out the differences, @pcbtt might come to the right result for the wrong reasons and will not understand when it is same and when it is not.